# Duplicated planes colour change

Tags: materials, objects, color

I've created a room in blender (one floor plane+ 3 wall planes) by duplicating the floor plane.  However, when I change the floor plane colour in materials all the other planes change also. How do I stop this and just assign a colour to one plane in view in 2.8.

Comment: You have to create a new material for each.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to duplicate, one is duplicate object in **Object Mode** and another is duplicate faces on **Edit Mode**.
When you duplicate objects, material also is duplicated applied automatically same as object from copied one.

[image]
To avoid this you have to add different material to each object from material Panel.
Click on **X** in material panel and delete old material, and then click on **New** to add new material to object. Do this to each object you want to have different material.
[image] [image] [image]

Let's check another possibility:
If you have duplicated faces in **edit mode**.
[image]
In such case add more **material slot** in same material panel by clicking **+** button beside material name;
[image]
Then click **New**.
[image]
After that select **face**, select **material slot** you want to be applied and then click on **assign**.
[image]
Now all faces are having different material.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!